# The value of NaN in Matlab seems to be wrong

Tags: matlab, nan, ieee-754, floating

The version of my MATLAB is:
9.3.0.713579 (R2017b)

According to IEEE 754-2008, the value of NaN in MATLAB is not correct:

```
>> format hex
>> single(+NaN)

ans =

  single

   ffc00000

>> single(-NaN)

ans =

  single

   7fc00000
```

Since the `MSB` of the binary value represents the sign of a single-precision floating point number, the value of `single(+NaN)` should be `7fc00000`, while the value of `single(-NaN)` should be `ffc00000`.

Is MATLAB wrong? Is it fixed in the latest version?

Comment: IEEE 754 does not say this is incorrect because it does not say which NaN MATLAB should produce when source text is `NaN`. It is up to MATLAB to define and document bindings to IEEE 754.

Comment: What does a sign mean when attached to a flag that indicates that the operation has no result? Why would anyone pay attention to that sign? Does MATLAB allow you to distinguish `NaN` and `-NaN`?

Answer (score 3):

> Is MATLAB wrong?

No.

There are [multiple representations of NaN in IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#NaN). In particular, the Sign bit may be either zero or one. Programs can use any of them, and Matlab doesn't claim to use any one in particular. `7fc00000` is one of them; `ffc00000` is another.